# Prolog program with lists and sublists

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

Hi I have to solve a problem in Prolog, that sounds like this: deletes all the sublists of a list that are increasing. For example the list [1,[2],[3,4],6] becomes [1,6].
So far I have tried this but it's not working. Any help please ?

```
    domains
 el=integer
 list=el*
 element=integer;list
 lista=element*

goal
elim([1,[2],[3],4)],L),
write(L).

predicates 
 elim(lista,lista)
 is_increasing(lista)
 is_list(lista)

clauses
is_increasing([A,B|T]) :- 
    B>A,
    is_increasing([B|T]).
is_list([_|_]).
is_list([]).
elim([],[]).
elim([E|Es],[E|Ts]) :-
    is_list(E),
    is_increasing(E),
    elim(Es, Ts).
```

Comment: You might want to mention which Prolog interpreter you're using (PDC Visual Prolog?). For starters, it looks like elements must be of the form `i(_)` or `l(_)`, but your elements are just integers and lists of integers. The way the code is written, it would expect a list like, `[i(1), l([i(2)]), l([i(3)]), i(4)]` or something like that. But then it would attempt to match a sublist, like `l([i(2)])` against `[...]` which won't match.

Comment: I'm using Turbo Prolog

Answer (score 0):

attempt to modularize your code: first write an is_increasing/1. Since it appears that a list of 1 element is increasing, you can do as simply as

```
is_increasing([A,B|T]) :- B > A, is_increasing([B|T]).
is_increasing([_]).
```

then you can use it to discard elements while *copying*. Beware to check that an element *is* a list before calling. Here is a possible definition

```
is_list([_|_]).
is_list([]).
```

*edit*

there is a bad declaration, as advised by mbratch

```
element=i(integer);l(list)
```

should be

```
element=integer;list
```

Also, you forgot `is_increasing([_]).`, and anyway you're not using at all is_list or is_increasing.

The rule eliminating sublists of course should read

```
elim([E|Es], Ts) :- is_list(E), is_increasing(E), elim(Es, Ts).
```

just add the base case and a copy. i.e. elim is a 3 clauses predicate...

*edit* apart the rule above, you need **only** a base case

```
elim([],[]).
```

and a copy

```
elim([E|Es],[E|Ts]) :- elim(Es, Ts).
```

just try to understand why the order of rules is also important in Prolog...

Comment: How should I put your code in the program? I'm sorry for being so dump but i'm new to prolog and I don't get it as I should.

Comment: declare them in `predicates` section (you already know how to declare that an argument is a list), add that code to `clauses` section, then simplify your elim, simply avoid to copy an element when `is_list(E), is_increasing(E)`

Comment: I have updated the question, and put the new clauses there. Still not working, now it says that the elem is not declared..

Comment: What do you mean that elim is a 3 clause predicate? I have elim(lista,lista) only 2. I have also tried to change my code, I don't know if it's ok

Comment: I give up, I have no more ideas :(

Comment: post your changes, I'll post my guess :)

Comment: I don't know what to change anymore. I've changed a lot before I thought of posting it here.

Comment: @jojuk your posted code still uses some `i(_)` and `l(_)` nomenclature which has been cited as incorrect. Those should be corrected.

Comment: how should I replace l(_) ?

Comment: simply remove both l(_) and i(_), that also you remove correctly from declaration

Comment: I changed it. I don't know if it's ok, I still get that error: undeclared predicate for elim. And before that I get a warning: Domain used as a functor

Comment: I think I fixed it. I've updated the question but now I have to fix that error that elim is not declared

Comment: @jojuk in your latest posted code, `elim([1,[2],[3],4)],L),` is a syntax error.

Comment: But I don't understand why...I give as a first parameter a list of integers and sublists, and the second one should be the same type, because it can return also a list of integers and sublists. Please help me with this declaration.

Comment: is_list and is increasing should take an *element*, because work on *lista' element*

Comment: I fear so, and I must confess I don't know how to declare it. What builtins turboprolog has to test **type** ?

Comment: is_list(E) takes an element, I think it should work, I can't run it because of that error undeclared predicate for elim. Does anyone know how to fix it? Please help me

Comment: move the `goal` section *after* `clauses`

Comment: Now it gives me a type error on 1 in the list that I pass in the goal

Comment: It gives me the same error even if I pass a simple list like [1,2,3,4]

Comment: change the is_list etc declaration to is_list(element) and add a clause is_list(_) :- fail.